# Manage printers / change passwords on multiple printers

Tags: password, hp, printer, print-server, manage

I need to change two specific settings on MANY printers. Most are HP. I was given a print server from someone who has left. I need to change all the notification emails to go elsewhere as well as the configuration admin password on each printer.

Please let me know how I can automate this.

Thanks,
-Mathew

Comment: When you do change the email address make it an alias so you can change the recipient easily in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a tool like HP Web JetAdmin you can set properties for many devices all at once. I just loaded it up here on my machine and after (auto) discovering all the printers in my building I could navigate to 'Tools' and there is a 'Multiple Device Configuration' option. This tool should let you do the tasks you want to accomplish in one fell swoop. It appears to be able to scan via IP range as well so you can do your entire network.

[Download here](http://h20338.www2.hp.com/hpsub/cache/332262-0-0-225-121.html)

Comment: Great. Installed the software and clicked "tools" and no "multiple device configuration" option was available. What am I missing?

Comment: Ahh apparently HP has updated the software behind my back and dropped that feature, the tricky buggers. Here's a link to the old version:
http://www.inet4u.com/Downloads/Utilities/hp%20web%20jetadmin/wja80-3366-xp-en.exe

Comment: Nice one Josh! Didn't know that there was a tool for that! I'll try it too.

Answer (score 1):

try through SNMP

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know if you are looking to change Printer's admin password or change the local admin password of you HP Server.

If it's a server, you can create your account (Or someone else with domain admin rights) can create you one. Then, you might be able to perform anything without the local admin account.

If you want to change the printer's admin password, you have 2 options.

Remotely on the printer web page by typing the IP address in your browser's address bar. You should have an option, depending the printer's model to setup the admin password.

The other one, kind of pain in the ass is to go directly on the printer and change it manually thru it.

Hope that helped!

Let me know!

Regards,
David.

Comment: David, I need to change the admin password on many printers.

Comment: The best way is to log onto the printer's web management page. If the printers are networked, it will be a lot easier than going on each printer one by one changing the admin password.

I've been searching for an apps that can massively change printer's password but no luck with that... 

Good luck!

Regards,
David.